# WPF CollectionViewSource.View null

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, collectionviewsource

I've got CollectionViewSource filtering from one trigger however I'm having problems getting it to have a second filter.
The problem is coming from the button in one view (MainWindow.xaml) having to be the trigger for the CollectionViewSource in PosterView.

PosterView.xaml

```
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GameListCVS"
                          Source="{Binding PosterViewOC}"
                          CollectionViewType="{x:Type dat:ListCollectionView}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Title" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

PosterView.xaml.cs

```
        private void SearchString_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        RefreshList();
        }
        public void RefreshList() 
        {
        GameListCV = ((CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("GameListCVS")));
        GameListCV.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(GenreFilter);
        GameListCV.Filter += new FilterEventHandler(GameSearch);
        if (GameListCV.View != null) //This is getting a null "GameListCV.View" on genre only, works if searchbar updated
            GameListCV.View.Refresh();
        }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
        private void ApplyGenreFilter_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        string genreToFilter = ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString();
        pv.GenreToFilter(genreToFilter);//passes the button tag and runs RefreshList();
        MenuToggleButton.IsChecked = false; //hide hamburger
    }
```

RefreshList() seems to get a view for CVS only if text is entered to the searchbar. 
I've tried adding a button in PosterView to refresh the GenreFilter, and that works fine, so it means that the problem is coming from the MainWindow having a button which then calls PosterView.RefreshList(); - it's not able to FindResource("GameListCVS")

Is there a workaround for this (some way of explicitly saying to FindResource - 'Look in PosterView for GameListCVS') - as currently the user has to search in the TextBox, delete it, and then they can filter genres fine

Comment: I don't understand your issue. When is the RefreshList() called? Before the view has been loaded?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to derive from ListCollectionView instead, and inside the constructor, you can set the CustomSort property there

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by derive from ListCollectionView instead?